# Can't execute commands via PHP and web server

Tags: php, command

I want to run [at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/at.1posix.html) command in PHP. Here is my file:

```
<?php
# at.php
    exec("echo ls | /usr/bin/at 02:00");
    $command = '/usr/bin/atq';
    exec($command, $output);
    print_r($output);
```

If I execute it by CLI: `php at.php`, it works well, But it doesn't work via web server in browser : `http://localhost/at.php`

I use ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 5.5 and I checked with nginx and apache2.

Comment: Check your disable_functions list in php.ini or from web with <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: I Couldn't find anything wrong. I set it empty, it didn't work. @Makinovic

Comment: Please define Doesn't work. What happens? what do you get in your error logs?

Comment: `$output` is empty and `exec("echo ls | /usr/bin/at 02:00");` doesn't create a new job in at queue. I checked logs(nginx/error.log, php5-fpm.log, syslog) nothing related to this code. @Anigel

Answer (score 0):

In Linux try **system** command

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

```
# at.php
    $last_line = system("ls | /usr/bin/at 02:00", $retval);
    print_r( $retval)
```